# Converting A Double To A Char In C#

Tags: c#, double

I am trying to complete a C# homework exercise in which, I have to ask for input for the cost of gas in liters, and the cost in gallons. Then compare the prices to discover which is actually the cheaper price. I can get my code to compare the price, then return the value which is the lowest, but can't seem to figure out how to get that value converted back to a string, which is the name of the station.
I am brand new to programming, so I'm stumped.
Following is my code:

```
//Programmer: Michael Davis
//Date: 10/22/14
//Purpose of program: To receive input regarding gas prices in liters and input in gallons, then compare prices to determine which is truly less expensive.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GasPriceComparison
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input1;
        string input2;
        char CanadianFuel;
        char AmericanFuel;
        double value1;
        double value2;
        double cheap;

        Console.WriteLine("How much is gas per litre at CanadianFuel?");
        input1 = Console.ReadLine( );

        Console.WriteLine("How much is gas per gallon at AmericanFuel?");
        input2 = Console.ReadLine( );

        value1 = double.Parse(input1);
        value2 = double.Parse(input2) * .264172;

        if (value1 > value2)
        {
            cheap = value2.ToChar[12](AmericanFuel);               
        }            
        else
        {
            cheap = value1.ToChar[12](CanadianFuel);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(("The cheaper gas is:  ") + cheap);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to have happen? What do you want to have displayed?

Comment: Pro Tip. Use `TryParse` instead of `Parse` so you can elegantly handle conversion errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is a relationship between the values you are accepting from the user, and a name or meaning for those values. To do this in an OO way you could define a class for your fuel types

```
public class FuelRegion
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double CostPerLitre { get; set; }

    public FuelRegion(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Then in your Main method instantiate one for American Fuel, one for Canadian Fuel and declare one for the cheapest:

```
FuelRegion americanFuel = new FuelRegion("American Fuel");
FuelRegion canadianFuel = new FuelRegion("Canadian Fuel");
FuelRegion cheapestFuel;
```

Now when you parse your values, instead of writing them to value1 and value2, write them to americanFuel.CostPerLitre and candadianFuel.CostPerLitre

```
candadianFuel.CostPerLitre = double.Parse(input1);
americanFuel.CostPerLitre = double.Parse(input2) * .264172;
```

Then you can compare the `CostPerLitre` of each region

```
if (candadianFuel.CostPerLitre > americanFuel.CostPerLitre)
{
    cheapestFuel = americanFuel;
}
else
{
    cheapestFuel = canadianFuel;
}
```

Now when you print to the console you can print the name of the cheapest fuel region:

```
Console.WriteLine("The cheaper gas is: {0}", cheapestFuel.Name);
```

One thing your logic doesn't handle is when the fuel prices are equal. If they are equal then you will always print that Canadian Fuel is cheapest.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!!!!
LOL, When I ask my professor a question like this, she just says, "It's either in your textbook, or you can Google it."
This makes sense now!

Comment: Great to know that it helped :) If this answer helped the most you can mark it as the accepted answer @MDavis0818

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. It's done. And, THANKS AGAIN!!

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is to call the `ToString()` method on `cheap`, like this:

```
if (value1 > value2)
{
    cheap = value2;
}
else
{
    cheap = value1;
}
Console.WriteLine(("The cheaper gas is:  ") + cheap.ToString());
```

However, that might not display it exactly the way you want. So you need to format it. You can write:

```
cheap.ToString("N2")
```

which will format it with two decimal places. You can also pass a format string to `Console.WriteLine`, like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("The cheaper gas is: {0:N2}", cheap);
```

Look up documentation for [Double.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx).